# Set relative position of an HTML element by its center

Tags: html, css

Image you have an HTML element e.g. a div which size depends on its dynamic content.
Now you want to place **its center** to a relative position compared to its parent. E.g. 20% in horizontal and 70% in vertical direction.

Is this possible without JavaScript, just with HTML and CSS?

If yes, how?

Example `div a` at 25% vertical and 75% horizontal and  `div b` at 75% vertical and 75% horizontal:

[image]

Comment: are you trying to center (both horizontally and vertically) your dynamic div inside the "static" one?

Comment: No! Not centering. Set the position of the center of the div element.

Comment: Show us what you tried. Post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `position: absolute` on the child and `position: relative` on the parent so the child can't escape.

Then basically use `left` and `top` to position the child in the parent element.

You need to use `transform: translate()` so the center of the child element ends up at the "coordinates" set by left and top.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  background-color: #ccc;
}

.parent > .absolute.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 70%;
  
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
    
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* move 50% of it's own width/height */

  background-color: rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

<div class="absolute child"></div>

<div>
```